# single line console output as a variable changes instead of one console.log per variable value?

Tags: node.js

Is there means in node.js to advance a counter within the console display to a single line, instead of a console.log output per line?

e.g.

```js
let x = 1
while (x <= 10) {
  console.log(`The value assigned to 'x' is now: ${x}`);
  x++;
  }
```

prints 10 lines for x = 1 through 10.

Is it possible instead to have a single line which remains static as the x value increments? As a use case, if the value of x incremented to one million, the console would display the one line until x was 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for a single line:

```
const process = require('process');
let x = 1;
process.stdout.write(`The count is now at: ${x}`);
const counter = () => {
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  x++;
  process.stdout.write(`The count is now at: ${x}`);
  if(x >= 10) {
    clearInterval(cycle);
    process.stdout.write('\n');
  }
};

const cycle = setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

...and then there's this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/log-update